# Is $Log|x| \in BMO((-\delta,\delta))$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I was asked to prove that $\log |x|$ is in $BMO(\mathbb{R})$. I did it and try to prove that $\log|x|\in BMO((-\delta, \delta))$. To my surprise I couldn't modify the proof.
Is it true at all? If so, I would be really grateful for any help.

Thank you!

Comment: The argument is really simple, see my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit : actually it's far more simple :

$$\|f\|_{BMO([-\delta,\delta])} = \sup_{[a,b]\subset [-\delta,\delta]} \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)-m_{[a,b]} | dx $$ $$ \leq \sup_{[a,b]\subset \mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} |f(x)-m_{[a,b]} | dx  = \|f\|_{BMO(\mathbb{R})}$$

---

Edit2 : removed pointless calculations

Comment: Yeah, I'd tried to prove it directly but this simple estimate works just as I needed:) Thank you:)